# Play Apple's .caf audio file on a webserver?

Tags: audio, audio-streaming

Play Apple's .caf audio file on a webserver?  I have .caf audio files (Apple's open audio format) stored on my webserver and want to play them from a web browser on any O/S.

Answer (score 2):

I understand, this doesn't seem like the solution you're looking for, but...

Several weeks ago we faced the same problem. We have several clients which are posting audio files to the web site from theirs iPhones, and we need to play audios on the web site.

But we didn't find any suitable flash player with `.caf` format support.

So we decided to convert `.caf` to `.mp3` on the server through the [`ffmpeg.exe` utility](http://www.ffmpeg.org/). 
Happily, there a lot of flash players with `.mp3` support.

Answer (score 0):

**Now I have not tried this... but...**

This website:

http://modmyi.com/forums/skinning-themes-discussion/1769-how-do-i-create-caf-file.html

Seems to suggest that `.CAF` and `.AIF` may work interchangeably (It suggests that to convert to `.CAF` you convert to `.`AIF` and then rename the file).

Have you tried renaming it to .AIF and trying to play in a flash/java browser player? Alternatively just send it as a stream to the web-browser and let the client OS work out what to do with it (Like quicktime running inside the browser).

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Just testing the renaming theory and it didn't work for me. The quicktime logo came up in my browser, but it had a giant question mark on it. Bummer. I was hoping the fix would be that easy. :)